# html page loading different after refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, css, refresh, loading

i am making something on a website, and i am loading in most of the html trough javascript. and for some reason something doesn't work the first time that you load the page, but does after refreshing.

here is what happends:

the first time that i load the page, this happends(the div is too big):

[image]

then after refreshing, this happends(this is what i want):

[image]

here is the code that i used:

```
this.text= "<div class='time mineBorderInvert' style='float:right;display:inline-block;'>0</div>"
this.el.html(this.text);

var H = this.el.find(".time").height();
this.el.find(".restart").css({width:H,height:H});
```

the variable h returns 32 the first time i load the page, but 21 after i refresh it. also this whole code iswithin a function that fires on the window.onload function.

the time div is the thing you can see in the right of the picture, and the restart div is the thing with the refresh icon.

so does anybody know why this doesn't work when first time loading the page

but does after refreshing?

Comment: Can you log var H to the console, and check the value on first load? Im guessing because the html is loaded dynamically via js, that H is empty, and your div is taking a default height

Comment: @Mark no it just returns as another value, first time i visit the site it returns as 34 but after reloading it returns 21, it is pretty strange

Comment: What height is correct?

Comment: where do you use that js-code? in document.ready function?

Comment: @demo the code is fired from window.onload

Comment: @Mark the correct height is 21, so after refreshing

Comment: this.text ="etc" try setting the height in the stile of the .time div

Comment: @Mark that kind of defeats the purpose though, i wanted the time to autosize. but i fixed it already in a pretty weird way :D. i basically used a interval that clears itself when it fires and has a 200 milsecond delay and i fired the

    var H = this.el.find(".time").height();
    this.el.find(".restart").css({width:H,height:H});

from within that.